# Understanding about a little code snippet in Sparc Assembly

Tags: assembly, sparc

From [this SPARC code](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~xyuan/cop5621/sparc.txt), I would like someone to confirm a confusion that I may do about the `set` instruction into SPARC assembly:

```
 main:
        /* I := J */
        ! Store address of J into local register %l7
        set     J, %l7
        ! Load value located by adress %l7 (address of J)  into %l0 register
        ! So put J value into %l0 register
        ld      [%l7], %l0
        ! Store address of I into local register %l7
        set     I, %l7
        ! Store value of %l0 (value of J) at adress of I
        st      %l0, [%l7]
        ! Finally, J value has overwritten the value of I
```

Finally, we can say that J value has overwritten the value of I. Is it correct?

Sorry for this simple question but I had confusions with `mov`, `set` and `st` instructions. Thanks

Comment: Yes, looks correct. You can try these things for yourself in a debugger.

Comment: thanks, I wanted this confirmation

Comment: Just last detail : If do                                                                                 .data
s0:     .asciz  "foo %s\n"
s1:     .asciz  "bar"
        .text
        .global main
main:
        save    %sp, -96, %sp
        set     s0, %o0
        set     s1, %o1         , then have I the address of s0 and s1 strings into respectively  %o0 and %o1 registers ?